# Add External JAR in Maven Dependency

Tags: maven

I am trying to add external JAR file [tigase-muc](https://projects.tigase.org/projects/tigase-muc/files) in a maven based project [tigase-server](https://projects.tigase.org/projects/tigase-server/files) in eclipse IDE.
I have tried following method

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Building Tigase XMPP Server 5.1.0 5.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install-file (default-cli) @ tigase-server ---
[INFO] Installing /home/haider/Downloads/tigase-muc-2.2.0.jar to /
home/haider/.m2/repository/tigase/tigase-muc/2.2.0/tigase-muc-2.2.0.jar
[INFO] --------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.791s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 05 18:06:48 PKT 2013
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 05 18:06:48 PKT 2013
[INFO] ----------------------
```

From above BUILD SUCCESS message i assume that JAR file is correctly added , but when i add following dependency in POM file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tigase</groupId>
            <artifactId>tigase-xmltools</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It give me following error **Missing artifact tigase:tigase-muc**. This message clearly indicate that it didn't get the JAR file that i am referring in dependency

*You Contribution will be highly appreciated THANKS*

Comment: Are you aware of the http://maven.tigase.org/ maven repository?

Comment: @tbsalling I just have checked it has same stuff as i have. Can u tell me whether my i am installing it in a right way or not 
any other suggestion will be highly appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it installs the Jar like this: [INFO] Installing /home/haider/Downloads/tigase-muc-2.2.0.jar to /
home/haider/.m2/repository/tigase/tigase-muc/2.2.0/tigase-muc-2.2.0.jar

As maven works, its group id is resolved to be ''tigase'', artifactId is ''tigase-muc'', version is ''2.2.0''
So this is right.

Now, I've took a look on tigase:tigase-xmltools:3.3.6 available [here](http://maven.tigase.org/tigase/tigase-xmltools/3.3.6/tigase-xmltools-3.3.6.pom)

It doesn't define any dependency at all.

So it looks like this would happen even if you don't specify this dependency :)

I would suggest you to run `mvn dependency:tree` to see where does this dependency comes from

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A more complete error message would help narrow down what's gone wrong.  The artifact you installed should be resolvable via the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>tigase</groupId>
    <artifactId>tigase-muc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

You're reference tigase-xmltools which I'm assuming has a dependency on tigase-muc.

My guess is tigase-xmltools might have dependency on the actual pom of tigase-muc, which you don't have despite having the jar.  Seeing the full error message and the pom of tigase-xmltools.

Installing the file with -D[generatePom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom)=true might help.

Comment: There is no error message at the time of adding JAR file with `maven install ` command. Instead it give me **BUILD SUCCESS** message.
But when i add dependency in POM file it give me error **issing artifact tigase:tigase-muc**

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have added the `jar` in maven dependencies, then it should be added in Maven Dependencies automatically.

Do you get any specific error while building the project? if yes then can you please share the error trace.

Also have a look at [Maven Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Also, verify your local maven repository - `M2_HOME\tigase\tigase-xmltools\3.3.6\` and check if the jar is installed here properly.

Comment: THANKS for replay
Please look at my question i have edited and showed some more detail of my problem

Comment: have you verified that the dependency definition in the `pom.xml` is correct, I can see the definition for `tigase-xmltools` in your question and not for `tigase-muc`

Answer (score 0):

You can install external jars in local repository.

Here is a blog -
http://findnerd.com/list/view/External-Dependencies-in-Maven-Project/3501/

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is use the embed lib repo:

[image]

and add local lib:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ok</groupId>
            <artifactId>comet4j-tomcat7</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lib</id>
            <name>lib</name>
            <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```